# AVERAGEIF in Excel with irregular range

Tags: excel, average

I know is a pretty basic question, but surprisingly, I can't seem to find a solution for it.

I'm looking to averageif every 10th cell that doesn't contain a 0 value, but for some reason the syntax doesn't work. I can't just take a range from between the first and last cell because there are other values in between that I don't want to be part of the average. I would have expected something like the below to work just fine, but it keeps returning an error message.

=AVERAGEIF(C4+C14+C24+C34+C44+C44,"<>0")

Any ideas? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a solution to my question (in case anyone comes across this in the future).

Instead of using AVERAGEIF, you can use a combination of the SUM and FREQUENCY functions.

To find the average of these cells [C4+C14+C24+C34+C44+C44] but exclude all 0 values, it looks like this:

=SUM(C4+C14+C24+C34+C44+54)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((C4+C14+C24+C34+C44+C54),0),2)

Credit to this blog for the help: http://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/conditional-average-on-non-contiguous-ranges-using-frequency/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a "helper column"

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT("C" & 4+10*(ROW()-1))
```

copy **B1** to **B2** thru **B6**

Then use:

```
=AVERAGEIF(B1:B6,"<>0")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. To complicate the matter even more, I also need to do the same thing for an even more irregular range of data (cells: E55,E85,E115,E145,E172,E199,E226,E253,E280,E307,E334,E361,E388,E415,E442,E469,E4‌​96,E523,E550,E577,E604). (It's every 30th cell four times, then every 27th cell another 17 times). Is your solution easily alterable/applicable for this too?

Comment: Perhaps..............each case is unique..........but the general technique is the same!